# HIPAA compliance in Microsoft computer vision?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

is computer vision already HIPAA compliant? Or, if it is not, will it be coming soon?

Edit: to further clarify: Microsoft categorizes its cloud services into categories. See here more information: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/TrustCenter/Compliance/HIPAA

I am asking if Computer Vision/Cognitive Services will be added into the in scope list.

Thanks!

Comment: @RobertColumbia, I have clarified my question. It is aimed at the MS engineers, I was directed by support over here. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunately, we are not Microsoft support. Your question would be better asked to Microsoft or to a support site for Microsoft products.

Comment: @RobertColumbia, That is correct. After talking with Microsoft Support, I was told that the engineers monitor this tag, and will answer my question over here.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Cognitive service Vision APIs are not currently HIPAA compliant. You can stay up to date with updates and announcements via [Cognitive Services Blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/topics/cognitive-services/)